# Java How to limit the amount of characters printed in a line

Tags: java, string

I’m looking for what I think is a very simple bit of code but I’m struggling to figure it out so let me try and explain as clearly as I can

Basically, I have a string let’s say for example string `Tweet =(“Happy Birthday”)`

And I have int called width which let’s just say is equal to `3`

How would I make it so the string prints only the amount of characters that squeal to the int width per line so it would look like this

```
Hap
Py 
Bir
Thd
Ay
```

Sorry again for the poor formatting I don’t know how better to explain it

Comment: Use a `for` loop to print each character of the string. Whenever the iterator is a multiple of 3, print a newline.

Comment: str.substring(0, Math.min(lineLength, str.length())

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public static void printLimit(String str, int lineLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(str.charAt(i));

        if ((i + 1) % lineLength == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're flushing the buffer everytime you call `System.out.print()`, so this isn't very performant.

Comment: @George I do not think that we're talking about performance here. By the way, you are not right, see implementation: `if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0)) out.flush();`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple version for beginner:

```
String tweet = null;
int limit = 3;
while(tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0 && tweet.length() > limit) {
    System.out.println(tweet.substring(0, limit));
    tweet = tweet.substring(limit);
}
if(tweet != null && tweet.length() != 0) {
    System.out.println(tweet);
}
else {
    System.out.println("tweet cannot be null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this task actually is hideous in java because of Unicode, here a limited Unicode solution:

- `char`s are UTF-16, sometimes a "surrogate" pair of two chars is needed for one Unicode symbol (*code point*). Putting a newline string in the middle is wrong.
- `é` can be one composed letter-e-with-accent or two: a letter-e and a combining diacritical mark for the accent (a zero width accent). I have used the `java.text.Normalizer` to compose it, `NFC`. Not `NFKC`which would also compose ligatures like in `ff`, `fi`and `ffi`.
- Not done: newline characters in the string, invisible characters, like a Right-To-Left control character.

So:

```
public static void printLinesWrapped(String text, int maxLineLength) {
    text = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
    AtomicInteger lineLength = new AtomicInteger();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maxLineLength * 2);
    text.codePoints()
        .forEach(cp -> {
            sb.appendCodePoint(cp);
            if (lineLength.incrementAndGet() >= maxLineLength) {
                System.out.println(sb);
                sb.setLength(0);
                lineLength.set(0);
            }
        };
    if (sb.length() != 0) {
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```